# Extending Protobuf Messages

Tags: inheritance, serialization, protocol-buffers, extends

I have many different schemas, however there are a set of fields which every schema contains. I was wondering if there was a way to have a different schema extend a parent schema and inherit its fields. For example this is what I want:

```
message Parent {
    required string common1 = 0;
    optional string common2 = 1;
}

message Child1 { // can we extend the Parent?
    // I want common1, common2 to be fields here
    required int c1 = 2;
    required string c2 = 3;
}

message Child2 { // can we extend Parent?
    // I want common1, common2 to be fields here
    repeated int c3 = 2;
    repeated string c4 = 3;
}
```

Such that Child1 and Child2 also contain the fields common1 and common2 (and potentially more) from Parent.

Is this possible and if so how?

Comment: Inheritance is not supported, but as a poor man's solution, you could use a nested construction where the first field of `Child1` and `Child2` is of type `Parent`. In order to access the fields in the "base-class", you will have to explicitly access that `Parent`-typed field first.

Comment: There are also extensions. https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto#extensions

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is not the exact answer to your question but we can do something like this to share common parameters.

```
message Child1 { 
    required int c1 = 2;
    required string c2 = 3;
}

message Child2 { 
    required int c1 = 2;
    required string c2 = 3;
}

message Request {
    required string common1 = 0;
    optional string common2 = 1;
    oneof msg { Child1 c1 = 2; Child2 c2 = 3; }

}
```

Other option is to use *extend* keyword

```
message Parent {
    required string common1 = 0;
    optional string common2 = 1;
}

message Child1 { 
    extend Parent
    {       
        optional Child1 c1 = 100;
    }

    required int c1 = 2;
    required string c2 = 3;
}
```

Comment: extend is not supported in proto buffer 3

Comment: So a parent has to know all the possible children, which can be in different files... ugly

Comment: @gtato check out Avro unions :)
All schemas need to be in one file, ive seen them grow to dozens lol

Comment: `oneof` creates nesting in JSON.

Comment: Ref: https://protobuf.dev/programming-guides/extension_declarations/#intro

Answer (score 2):

Although inheritance is not directly supported in protobuf, in some languages (e.g. C#) you can still create common contracts for a service/request/reply etc. using partial classes.

You can create a partial class of the generated one, and have it inherit/implement your common scenario.

In this way you can ensure a common contract in your internal models and services.

Note however, that this is for internal use only, as the endpoints and API surface should be completely oblivious to your specifications.